# Carto Builder is enabled but I'm still seeing the old editor

Tags: carto

After taking a break from mapping, I've just logged back into Carto. My Carto account has builder enabled, but I'm still seeing the old editor when I look at my datasets and maps? The profile account dashboard has been updated but not the editor?

How do I fix this? I've tried creating and publishing a new map to see if that would "activate" the new builder but it hasn't.

Note: I created the account years ago when it was CartoDB

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Although CARTO is currently encouraging older users to migrate to the new UI, Builder, the change hasn't been enforced yet. If you wish to switch from Editor to Builder all you have to do is send us an email to support@carto.com and we'll take care of that for you.

Before switching to Builder, there are some things you may want to note:

1) After the migration, user's can't be switched back to the older CARTO Editor. This is due to the fact that Editor is currently being deprecated, and technical support, bug fixes, etc; won't be available any more.

2) So many things have changed between CARTO Editor and Builder that many features are not compatible. Although many changes have been taken towards ensuring that older Editor maps won't break when opened with Builder, its still not recommended to do so. Some features, such as logo's or text over the map, are not available in Builder and can't be edited in the new UI.

3) CARTO.js was made specifically for Editor and, as such, it is not yet compatible with Builder. Until the new CARTO.js release, Builder does not offer the possibility of extracting viz.json files to help customizing maps with JavaScript.

That said, there are a ton of new features available in Builder, which you can learn about by checking our [CARTO Guides](https://carto.com/learn/guides).

**Note**: I'm currently working in CARTO's Support Team